# ¿Promediar datos de un csv de acuerdo a datos de otra columna?

Tags: python

Me explico, tengo un csv sobre casos de Covid donde una columna llamada "Tipos", tiene 3 tipos los cuales son Importado, Relacionado y En estudio y de estos hay varios, son 9660 datos y de acuerdo a cada tipo debo promediar las edades de la columna "Edad" de acuerdo a que tipo tengan y al final hacer un diccionario como este:

```
    {'casos_en_estudio': 4558,
'prom_edades_casos_en_estudio'
: 42, 'casos_importados': 813,
'prom_edades_casos_importados'
: 42, 'casos_relacionados': 4589,
'prom_edades_casos_relacionado
s': 37, 'total_casos': 9960}
```

Ya se que de la forma `.value_counts.sort_index(ascending=True)` puedo contar el total de los casos en estudio, importados y relacionados pero no se como sacar las edades de acuerdo a cada tipo y promediarlas para hacer el diccionario.

[Enlace del csv para ver los datos](https://bitbucket.org/ingluise2019/misiontic/downloads/Casos_positivos_de_COVID-19_en_Colombia.csv)

Comment: ya puse el enlace del csv, no se me habia puesto

Comment: ok, ahora lo reviso y te doy la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Ok para esto, tendremos que agrupar los datos, para ello nos apoyaremos del método `groupby`, mi primera opción era obtener los datos por separad, pero para mi era mucho código (4 líneas mas) y pues te dire como hacerlo obtienedo el resultado que deseas.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv") #le pones el nombre de tu archivo

#agrupamos y operamos con los valores
datos = df.groupby("Tipo").apply(lambda x: [x["Edad"].mean(), x["Tipo"].count()]).to_dict()
print(datos)
```

**resultado**

```
{'En estudio': [42.32711715664765, 4558],
 'Importado': [42.85485854858548, 813],
 'Relacionado': [37.632817607321854, 4589]}
```

Hemos utilizado el método  `df.groupby("Tipo")` Donde agrupamos de acuerdo a la columna `Tipo`, luego usamos el método `apply()` para *aplicarle* una operación, qu es `.apply(lambda x: [x["Edad"].mean(), x["Tipo"].count()])` donde obtenemos las columnas `Edad` y `Tipo` con `x["Edad"]` y `x["Tipo"]` finalmente usamos `.mean()` para sacar el promedio (solo en la edad) y `.count()` para contar los datos (en la columna Tipo) y para finalizar lo convertimos a diccionario con `.to_dict()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Casos_positivos_de_COVID-19_en_Colombia.csv")

tipos = set(df.Tipo)

mi_dic = {}
for tipo in tipos:
    mi_dic['casos_'+tipo.replace(" ","_")] = df.loc[(df.Tipo==tipo),"Edad"].count()
    mi_dic['prom_edades_casos_'+tipo.replace(" ","_")] = df.loc[(df.Tipo==tipo),"Edad"].mean()

mi_dic
```

Output:

```
{'casos_Relacionado': 4589,
 'prom_edades_casos_Relacionado': 37.632817607321854,
 'casos_En_estudio': 4558,
 'prom_edades_casos_En_estudio': 42.32711715664765,
 'casos_Importado': 813,
 'prom_edades_casos_Importado': 42.85485854858548}
```

Después de cargar el CSV, creamos la lista `tipos` con los valores únicos de la columna `Tipo`. Luego iniciamos un objeto diccionario vacío y con un bucle vamos rellenando tanto los casos como el promedio de edades.

El cálculo de cada promedio y edad es simplemente aprovechando el método `loc`, que nos permite localizar qué filas del dataframe cumplen una serie de condiciones y devolver un conjunto de columnas en específico.

Por ejemplo, `df.loc[(df.Tipo==tipo),"Edad"]` significa algo así como "localízame todas las filas cuyo Tipo = "En Estudio" pero devuélveme sólo la columna Edad.

Con eso calculamos promedios y contamos el total de registros.

La parte de `replace` era por intentar cuadrarlo lo máximo posible a tu ejemplo del output esperado.

> [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: Gracias, y hay alguna forma de organizar para que se muestren primero los casos en estudio, luego los importados y luego los relacionados? También será que puedo convertir los promedios a enteros con int()?

Comment: @Rinxs para que salgan en el orden que tú quieras, construye la lista `tipos` manualmente, algo como `tipos = ["En estudio","Importado","Relacionado"]`. Para lo segundo, redondea a 0 decimales y pásalo a int si quieres y listo.